# Substituting prepositional phrases

Tags: prepositions, grammatical-subject

In English, if you take the sentence *behind the house was untidy*, what is untidy is really an area behind the house – so assuming for now that *behind the house* can be regarded as the subject of the sentence (more below), that PP stands for an area which can be said to be *behind the house*, or in other words an NP to which it would apply.

In Thai, unless I have misunderstood, if you want to say *he is angry because of you*, you say *because (of) you made him angry*, where the PP is the subject and stands for *a situation caused by you* - so again, an NP to which the PP would apply.

Is this a recognised phenomenon, and does it have a name?

As to the subject of the English sentence, I posted something on EL&U that was intended to explore this, but chose a bad example (*behind the house was a culvert*) and got nowhere – it was immediately pointed out that the subject of that sentence is *a culvert*.

That analysis doesn’t work for *behind the house was untidy*, though. I suppose this could be seen as a transformation of *it was untidy behind the house*, but I’m not sure that would explain or simplify anything. Then there is the sentence *behind the house was laid out to lawn*. I’d be interested to know whether this strikes people as correct (intuitively, I mean). If it is correct, isn’t *behind the house* the subject, and doesn’t it stand for *the area behind the house*?

Comment: As you suggest, the PP in "[behind the house] was untidy" is interpreted as "the area behind the house", an NP. But the PP in "[Behind the house] was a culvert" doesn't mean 'the area behind the house' -- it can't be interpreted as an NP, so it can't be the subject.

Comment: @BillJ Sure, that was just a poorly chosen example (based on a Thai sentence in which the word corresponding to *was* cannot mean *lay, was situated*, so the natural reading in En is not available). Any view on *behind the house was laid out to lawn* ?

Comment: I'd say that "behind the lawn" also behaves like an NP (the area behind the house). It must be the subject because "was laid out to lawn" is a passive verb phrase, and hence cannot be the subject.

Comment: A further comment about your "culvert" example: we could replace "a culvert" with "two culverts", which would require that we replace "was" by "were", with the agreement showing that "a culvert" is the subject. And in "behind the house was laid to lawn", we could have an interrogative tag, "wasn't it?", where "it"  is anaphoric to "behind the house, showing that the latter is subject.

Comment: Shall I put up a proper answer?

Comment: @BillJ Sure, go ahead and I’ll be happy to accept. At some point it occurred to me that there were three cases but just now I can only think of two - (1) the prep is a valid argument or predicate of whatever is on the other side of a copular verb, e.g. *under the stairs is where I kept them, *after 9 is too late* (2) the prep stands for an NP of which it could be predicated, e.g. *behind the house was laid out to lawn*...

Comment: ... This does not seem different in principle from x *because of you made him angry*, where *because of you* stands for *a situation that you brought about*. One difference is that in the first case the NP would take a definite article, whereas in the second it is indeterminate, but that can’t be all there is to it or we would accept *because of you made him angry* but understand it as *the situation that you brought about you did made him angry*, and only use it when we already knew what situation we were talking about.